# Installing 12.10 via DVD, Don't get install along side Windows 7 option?

Tags: installation, 12.10, dvd

Don't want to install via the Windows installer.  Have burned the ISO and booted from CD.  When I select the option to install, I'm not getting the option to "Install along side Windows 7" which the instructions state it should be there.  Any way to get this to show up?

Answer (score 1):

Rookie mistake - Forgot to set up the initial partition allowing the installation alongside Windows.  Set up the partition shrinking the main hard drive, then tried again.  Option showed up as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Run the disc inside Windows and use the Wubi installer. This will install Ubuntu in the Windows Program Files Directory so you can choose which OS to run at startup and uninstall Ubuntu at any given time.